# audio base 64 blob to linear16

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, google-cloud-speech

I am using media recorder to get user audio and want to send it to google speech to text. mediaRecorder return blob audio base 64 i need to convert it to linear 16. I am struggling to understand how to start this process. how does the base64 relate to the audio data, how many bites per element. how to i then maintain that in the linear16. just looking for documentation really on how this coul be do been thrown down a rabbit hole

only way i have got this to work so fare is taking user content and manualy putting through a wave converter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.